# Jackson ObjectMapper deserialize an object which contains an array of objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I serialize this kind of object:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

private String type;
...
private String[] target;

//getters and setters
}
```

But when I try to deserialize `MyObject` I get an error because of the `target` array.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->MyObject["target"])
...
```

How can I deserialize an array ?

Comment: it seems that Jackson is trying to deserialise a String, not an array of Strings. Maybe there is a mistake in the setter method?

Comment: Show us your json, maybe there's a mistake there.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I did not see that I had 2 setters un the class. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. I did not see I had 2 setters in the class. Jackson was probably using the wrong one.

I just had to put the annotation `@JsonSetter("target")` above the setter which accept an array to tell Jackson to use the good one.

```
public void setTarget(String target) {
    this.target = new String[]{target};
}

@JsonSetter("target")
public void setTarget(String[] target) {
    this.target = target;
}
```